# Compiling node-sass failed due to cannot find node_version.h

Tags: node.js, windows, node-sass

I was building node-sass with the following config:

- Windows 10 64bit
- node v4.4.3 LTS 64bit
- node-sass 0.3.6
- Visual Studio 2015

I have cloned node repo from git and added src to PATH, but I still got these errors:

```html
“C:\Users\a\Project\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln”(默认目标) (1) ->
“C:\Users\a\Project\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj”(default target) (2) ->
“C:\Users\a\Project\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj”(default target) (4) ->
(ClCompile target) ->
  C:\Users\a\Project\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\nan\nan.h(23): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'node_version.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\binding.cpp) [C:\Users\a\Project\P
latform\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\a\Project\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\nan\nan.h(23): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'node_version.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\create_string.cpp) [C:\Users\a\Pro
ject\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\a\Project\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\nan\nan.h(23): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'node_version.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\custom_importer_bridge.cpp) [C:\Use
rs\a\Project\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\a\Project\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\nan\nan.h(23): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'node_version.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\custom_function_bridge.cpp) [C:\Use
rs\a\Project\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\a\Project\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\nan\nan.h(23): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'node_version.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\color.cpp) [C:\Users\a\
Project\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\a\Project\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\nan\nan.h(23): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'node_version.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\boolean.cpp) [C:\Users\a\Project\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\a\Project\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\nan\nan.h(23): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'node_version.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\error.cpp) [C:\Users\a\
Project\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\a\Project\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\nan\nan.h(23): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'node_version.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\factory.cpp) [C:\Users\a\Project\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\a\Project\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\nan\nan.h(23): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'node_version.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\list.cpp) [C:\Users\a\P
roject\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\a\Project\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\nan\nan.h(23): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'node_version.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\map.cpp) [C:\Users\a\Pr
oject\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\a\Project\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\nan\nan.h(23): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'node_version.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\null.cpp) [C:\Users\a\P
roject\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\a\Project\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\nan\nan.h(23): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'node_version.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\number.cpp) [C:\Users\a
\Project\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\a\Project\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\nan\nan.h(23): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'node_version.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\string.cpp) [C:\Users\a
\Project\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\a\Project\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\nan\nan.h(23): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'node_version.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_context_wrapper.cpp) [C:\Users
\a\Project\Platform\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
```